# Accessing index of array of buttons then pushing to different VC with info

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform, indexing, swift2

In an app for creating events each collection view cell has an array of buttons whose backgrounds display the profile pictures of the users attending said event (object at index path). This works all fine and good, with them displaying correctly but I want to make it so that when a user selects a certain button it pushes to a profile view controller with the user who the photo belongs to.

Here is the code I have so far...

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method of main VC... like I said it displays perfectly.

```
            //gets profile pictures for image view array on back of cell

            if let attendeeRelation : PFRelation = event?.relationForKey("eventAttendees") {

                attendeeRelation.query()?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                    if ((objects) != nil) {

                        self.tempArray = objects as? [PFUser]

                        for var index = 0; index < objects!.count; ++index {

                            let buttonView = cell.buttonsArray[index]

                            let usr : PFUser = (self.tempArray?[index] as PFUser?)!

                            usr.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in

                                if let picture = object!.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
                                    picture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in                      
                                        buttonView.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(data: data!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }

                    else {

                        print(error)
                    }

                })

            }
```

Prepare for segue method, where I'm having trouble...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "pushToProfile") {

        //get index of button here then push to profile VC with correct user

        let profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileViewController
    }
}
```

Should I just subclass the button and give it a user property and go from there? I feel like that might be the easiest way. Anyone else have suggestions? Thank you and much appreciated like always.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

Subclassing the button and giving it a "user" property did the trick.